# Send Custom Acknowledgement message to sender using jms:inbound-channel-adapter using spring integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-jms

I wand to send costume message as (Message Received) to producer queue client once its was received by consumer queue client using jms inbound channel adapter. Need help how to achieve this or any alternative way using xml configuration.

XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:int-file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml"
    xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc" 
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc/spring-integration-jdbc.xsd   
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd">
        
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.fcb.incoming.wires" />
    
    <context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath:application-default.properties, classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" />   
        
    <int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="${fcb.queue.poller.fixeddelay}"/>   
    
    <int:channel id="incomingWireChannel">
        <int:queue />
    </int:channel>
    <int:channel id="interWireChannel">
       <int:queue />
    </int:channel>
   <int:channel id="verifyWireChannel">
       <int:queue />
    </int:channel>   
     
     
     <jms:inbound-channel-adapter
        channel="incomingWireChannel" connection-factory="${fcb.queue.mq.connection.factory}"
        destination-name="${fcb.incoming.wires.req.queue}" acknowledge="client">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="${fcb.queue.poller.fixeddelay}" />
    </jms:inbound-channel-adapter> 
    
    <int:router input-channel="incomingWireChannel" ref="msgValidator" method="validate"  />    
    
    <bean id="msgValidator" class="com.fcb.incoming.wires.validate.MessageValidator">       
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an [outbound channel adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jms.html#jms-outbound-channel-adapter) or use an [inbound gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/jms.html#jms-inbound-gateway).

> Spring Integration’s message-driven JMS inbound-gateway delegates to a MessageListener container, supports dynamically adjusting concurrent consumers, and can also handle replies.

Comment: It's not clear what you have downstream; you have a router, which references a validator bean (whatever that is). Some component downstream of the gateway simply needs to return a reply and the framework will route it back to the gateway. See [the JMS Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jms).

Comment: i have made the changes as per your suggestion <jms:inbound-gateway id="jmsInGateway" request-destination-name="${acb.inbound.error.queue}" request-channel="inbounderrorChannel" connection-factory="${acb.queue.mq.connection.factory}" acknowledge="client" />and its working fine as i am receiving the message from queue but not aware to set custom message and reply back to sender